# Initializing an Array - Public Static int[]

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I am writing a code that takes an array of integers and should return a new array with only the positive integers. I wrote my code, but I am not sure how to test it i.e. initialize an array. Here is the code

```
public static int [] getPositiveNumbers(int[] numbers)
{
    int count = 0;
    int [] result =  new int[count];
    for(int pos = 0; pos < numbers.length; pos++)
    {
        if(numbers[pos] > 0)
        {
        result[count] = numbers[pos];
        count += 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Now I am not entirely sure if the code is correct, but I will test it so I don't need feedback on that, unless there is something in my code that will affect initialization.

Do I need to write a test class for this? And if so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: `count = 0` so you are creating array `result[]` of size zero. Why dont you add main() function and call your getPositiveNumbers() method from within main()

Comment: "Do I need to write a test class for this?" - define "need". Java has no such concept as a "test class", never mind forcing you to write one.

Comment: **First solution:** If you want to use  `int [] result = new int[count];` you have to determine the size of `count` before.  Write a loop to count positive integers then allocate the `result` array.  You will have to do a second loop to transfer the positive numbers.  **Second solution:** If you want to do it in a single loop, you must use a dynamically allocated array, this is done with `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write tests if you need. Tests are just there to help (secure your code, test a business in particular, you can also made integration test for high level testing). So it's up to you, follow your needs.

For the content of your function, you can try this :

```
public static int[] getPositiveNumbers(int[] numbers) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int n : numbers) {
            if (n > 0) {
                result.add(n);
            }
        }
        int[] array = new int[result.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) array[i] = result.get(i);

        return array;
    }
```

And here the test for this method :

```
/**
 * Test of getPositiveNumbers method
 */
@Test
public void testGetPositiveNumbers() {
    System.out.println("getPositiveNumbers");
    int[] numbers = {2, 3, -9, 4, -29, 50, -34, -32};
    int[] expResult = {2,3,4,50};
    int[] result = ToDelete.getPositiveNumbers(numbers);
    assertArrayEquals(expResult, result);
}
```